# Most efficient method for managing database connections using AWS Lambda functions and AWS RDS (PostgreSQL Aurora)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, entity-framework-core, amazon-rds

I have a .NET Core 3.1 application which consists of an AWS API Gateway, a set of Lambda functions, and an RDS Aurora PostgreSQL database for reading and writing to. This application uses Entity Framework Core for the database connection and query execution. I am trying to understand - of the two available connection methods I can see available - which is the correct one to use for performance, efficiency and best use of resources within the context of AWS Lambda containers / serverless.

Option 1)
Maintain a single DBContext connection, opened outside the function handler(s) of my Lambda functions, and passed around in and out of all the methods requiring said connection. E.g.

```
public class Functions
{
    private readonly loyaltyContext loyaltyContext;
    public Functions()
    {
        loyaltyContext = new loyaltyContext();
    }
}
```

Then within each handler:

Refer to it:

```
            var testEfCore = (from c in loyaltyContext.ContactInformation
                select c.ContactInternalId).Take(1);
```

Pass it into other methods:

```
                    var duplicateError = await BusinessRules.DuplicateCustomerCheck(customer, loyaltyContext);
```

Option 2)

Create, use and dispose the DbContext at each point it is required, within the handler, and the methods and functions it calls, e.g.

```
    public static bool IsCardExist(string cardNumber, string cardState)
    {
        using (var loyalty = new loyaltyContext())
        {
            var existingCard = (from c in loyalty.ExternalCards
                                where c.CardNumber == cardNumber
                                && c.CardStatus == cardState 
                                select c.CardNumber).Any();

            return existingCard;
        }
    }

    public static void SomeOtherFunctionCalledByHandler ()
    {
        using (var loyalty = new loyaltyContext())
        {

        }
    }
```

And so on.

Comment: Have you looked into RDS proxy? It just came out of preview, but seems to be a good solution for managing your connections from Lambda to RDS: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-rds-proxy-with-aws-lambda/

Comment: When I last checked it was in preview and not in our Sydney region. If that's changed, I'll check it out. But if that's not an option, I'd be interested in views on the original question. Cheers.

Comment: How often does your Lambda run?  Have you timed the difference?

Comment: It's driven by an API, so it's not scheduled, the traffic will be variable depending on time of day etc, but am expecting thousands of invocations of each function daily. I have not timed the difference, as I'm not even sure that both options are architecturally valid, which is why I'm here first.